# How to make Data.List.Vector a member of Arbitrary easily?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, quickcheck

I am using the Data.List.Vector in my program, and now I would like to use quickCheck for it. However, there is no instance for that. Since there already is an arbitrary for [Double], I thought I could do something like

```
instance Arbitrary V.Vector Double where
    arbitrary = V.fromList (arbitrary :: [Double])
```

alas, GHC does not like this at all:

```
`Arbitrary' is applied to too many type arguments
In the instance declaration for `Arbitrary V.Vector Double'
```

I guess I could also just make a bunch of properties that take in a [Double] and uses V.fromList, but that seems tedious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to parenthesize it, like `instance Arbitrary (V.Vector Double)`, etc. But there's a better way to do it:

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (V.Vector a) where
    arbitrary = fmap V.fromList arbitrary
```

Note that you need the `fmap` because `arbitrary` is a value of type `Gen a`, and so in order to go from `Gen [a]` to `Gen (V.Vector a)` you need to lift `V.fromList` into `Gen`, which you can do since it's a functor.